# new to bash script cant understand the following code

Tags: json, linux, shell

Can someone please explain the code below, by breaking it down in parts, especially this part: `sed -i '$s/}/`

```
sed -i '$s/}/,\n"location":"canada"}/' sample.json
```

output

```
{"name" :"sam",
"age":23,
"designation":"doctor",
"location":"canada"}
```

Comment: It's adding a field to a json object the wrong way - should be using `jq` or another tool that actually understands JSON instead of doing a simple but fragile and error-prone text substitution.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is an external command (stream editor) commonly found on linux systems.

- `-i` means it changes the input file in place.
- `$` is the "address", it means the following command will only be applied to the last line.
- `s///` is a "substitution", it replaces `}` with a newline and `"location":"canada"}`

  jq '.location="canada"'  file.json

The better way would be to use `jq` which can understand JSON.

```
jq '.location="canada"' file.json
```